# pyo3 optionally generate python bindings for rust struct

Tags: rust, pyo3

I have defined a few structs in my code and if a certain feature is enabled on the crate, I would like to generate Python bindings for those structs as well. Right now I am not able to get it correctly. Let's say I have a struct `MyStruct` for which I want to optionally generate Python Bindings.

I have tried something like the following

```rust
cfg_if! {
    if #[cfg(feature = "python-bindings")] {
        #[pyclass]
    } 
    else {
    }  
}
struct MyStruct{
   value: i32
}
```

I would like to only add `#[pyclass]` if `feature` `python-bindings` is enabled and not otherwise.

This works fine if `python-bindings` is not enabled. But if I compile with `--features python-bindings`, I get the following error.

`error: expected item after attributes`

As far as possible I do not want to duplicate the code. like

```rust
cfg_if! {
    if #[cfg(feature = "python-bindings")] {
        #[pyclass]
        struct MyStruct{
           value: i32
        }
    } 
    else {
        struct MyStruct{
            value: i32
        }
    }  
}
```

Is there a way of doing it without duplicating the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with [`#[cfg_attr]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg_attr-attribute):

```rust
#[cfg_attr(feature = "python-bindings", pyclass)]
struct MyStruct {
    value: i32
}
```